# Should i install Windows on the fastest sequential drive or fastest random write drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, installation, performance, speed

I currently have 4 HDDs in my rig and i want to set it up in the most performant way.
My fastest sequential write drive (2) can write at 85MB/s with 0.95MB/s random write speed.
However my slowest drive (1) with 55MB/s sequential speed can write at 1.3MB/s random.

Space is not important for me. Which drive would run Windows the best/fastest? I'd like to keep one of the faster ones as an application drive (heavy software).

Here are all benchmarks using CrystalDiskMark: http://pastebin.com/MPNaMbmS

Comment: Generally speaking I would install on the faster random **read** drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is going to be a system/boot drive you will benefit more with fastest READ speeds, you will not be writing much to the drive except when first install and updates, and most requests for data will be RANDOM, so the fastest random read speed would give you the most benefits, large files (like databases) would benefit from sequential read speeds and writes, so its better to have those in your data drive.